# BIND9 logging only specified view

Tags: domain-name-system, logging, bind, internal-dns

For diagnosing purposes I need to log BIND9 queries.
BIND9 is configured with two zones/views (internal/external).

I've configured logging but there is a lot of unnecessary queries being logged - from internal view.

How can I configure BIND9 to log only external queries (view "external")?